# frequency analysis, someone who knows how to solve this problem. I can't tell how many times the letter can come

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program that can read a text from a file and do frequency analysis
on the letters that appear To
store information (frequency) you should use an array as follows.
- Create an array with space for 127 int
- Read one letter at a time, convert it to int (char-> int). The value comes
to correspond to the ascii code of the letter. Update the "counter" on
respective index in the array.
Example! The place where you count the frequency of eg the letter A is
corresponded to the ASCII code of "A" ie 65.

```
    int[] array = new int[127];


    Scanner scan = null;
    int c = 0;
    try {

        scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\-------\\eclipse- 
       workspace\\algo_data\\src\\klasslista.txt"));

        while(scan.hasNext()){

            String str = scan.next();
            char[] myChar = str.toCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < myChar.length; j++) {
                for (char i = 65; i < 123; i++) {
                    if(myChar[j] == i) {
                        //array[i] = myChar[j];
                        array[i] = myChar[j];  

                   How can it count and the letters??


                    }


                }

            }

            for (int i = 65; i < array.length; i++) {

                System.out.print((char)array[i]);

            }
```

Comment: Don't just copy and paste the assignment into stack overflow. We won't do it for you. You have clearly made a start, so **explain** what you have tried, what results you got, and how that differs from what you were expecting. "When I ______, I get ______, when I am expecting to get ______"

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have there? What are you stuck on? I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't count the letters.  The ASCII code is the array index you are looking for.  Increment the int at that index by one every time you encounter the letter.  The int at the index that represents that ASCII code is your counter for how many times the character occurs. The default value of each index in the array should be -1 so if it is then you need to set it to 1, else increment the value there by 1.

```
    int[] array = new int[127];
    Scanner scan = null;

    try {

        scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\-------\\eclipse-workspace\\algo_data\\src\\klasslista.txt"));

        while (scan.hasNext()) {

            String str = scan.next();
            char[] myChar = str.toCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < myChar.length; j++) {
                int temp = array[(int) myChar[j]];
                if (temp == -1) {
                    array[(int) myChar[j]] = 1;
                } else {
                    array[(int) myChar[j]] = temp + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
            char c = (char) i;
            System.out.println("Count of " + c ": " + array[i]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

    }
```

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < myChar.length; j++) {
     for (char i = 65; i < 123; i++) {
      if(myChar[j] == i) {
       array[i] = myChar[j];
       

      }


     }

Comment: I have loops as I read. I run from 65 to 123 to get ascci values. I find the value and I put it in array [i]. The error is that every time I find a letter I should count. I do not stand how to do it.

Comment: What I'm saying is don't put the ascii value in the array.  Use the ascii value as the index of the array and put your count for that character at that index.

Comment: thanks for the help it wrote out a few digits.
but does not match the number of letters.

Comment: Maybe you weren't printing it right.  I've added the print code.  Printing should be done outside of the loop.

Comment: I wonder why I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
int temp = array [(int) myChar [j]];
they mean that there is no value in the array. How do I solve this?

Comment: Your file must have characters in the extended ascii table.  You can add a check to make sure it's less than 127 and continue to the next letter if it isn't. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help and thank you for showing me how to do it. it works as it should